# Disaster-driven tourism to newly-exposed locales

Tags: factoids, natural-disasters

There are a few questions here about whether tourism monies ameliorate the effects of a disaster, and this lends some credence to a theory that a disaster can drive additional traffic to a region that had a history of tourism. Possible examples: Perugia, Italy post-earthquake, Indonesia post-tsunami.

This question asks if there are any known regions where a near-term disaster opened up **new** tourism inflows? This is mostly driven by the current wildfires in Chile. It led me to ask if certain undiscovered primitive sites were exposed through a disaster like fire? Something like hidden Mayan or Aztec ruins via a jungle wildfire? Or possibly, hidden lake-engulfed cities exposed by drought?

Comment: Never heard of a positive impact. As an anecdote, I was in Indonesia after a disaster and it was ghostly. Even in Bali, I had entire kilometers of beaches to myself. I flew back on a Boeing 767 where we were less than 10 passengers!

Comment: In the aftermath of the Yellowstone fires of 1988, the number of known waterfalls in the park doubled.  Don't know if it had an impact on the tourist numbers, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect hiking to the top of Mount Pinatubo might fit in this category.

A fair-sized lake now graces the summit where a lot of rock was previously. At least 846 people died in the 1991 eruption so it certainly qualifies as a disaster.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Pinatubo#Hiking_Pinatubo) (original source link is currently dead, emphasis added):

> The caldera formed and Lake Pinatubo has **since become** a tourist attraction with the preferred route through Barangay Santa Juliana in Capas, Tarlac.